# Published Failed my WCF service

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, publish

And My OutPut Window is this:

> ------ Build started: Project: WcfService, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------   WcfService ->
>   C:\Users\Zaid\Downloads\WcfService\WcfService\WcfService\bin\WcfService.dll
>   ------ Publish started: Project: WcfService, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------ Connecting to http://**someIP**:xxxx... Unable to create
>   the Web site 'http://**someIP**:xxxx'.  The server unexpectedly closed
>   the connection.
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
>   ========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

As it Works Perfectly on IIS Server. And my Code in Web.config File is:

```
    ![<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfService.IService1"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://14.200.162.57:6968/WcfService/Service1.svc"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>][1]
```

My Publish Method is:

> FPSE

Comment: Please improve your title. The title should say something about what happens when you publish your WCF service.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Saunders Ok but this is not Answer of my Problem!!!